# Flutter how to sort and group a map of data

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, fluttermap

I'm retrieving a map of data from api as follows

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "sequenceno": 1933,
                "_id": "5eff1",
                "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                "title": "Place Value: 3-digits",
                "package_description": "This learning module helps to familiarise with the concept of place value of 3-digit numbers.",
                "age_level": [
                    99,
                    8
                ],
                "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                "packagescors": {
                    "score": [
                        50
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "1600259121340"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "sequenceno": 1933,
                "_id": "5d79",
                "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                "title": "Place Value: 4-digits",
                "package_description": "This learning module helps the kids familiarise with the concept of Place value of a number.",
                "age_level": [
                    99,
                    8
                ],
                "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                "packagescors": {
                    "score": [
                        60
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "1615283866457"
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
```

My objective is sort and group them with the key 'Chapter'. as given below

```
           Numbers and Numeration : { // chapter name 
                    "sequenceno": 1933,
                    "_id": "5d79",
                    "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                    "title": "Place Value: 4-digits",
                    "package_description": "This learning module helps the kids familiarise with the concept of Place value of a number.",
                    "age_level": [
                        99,
                        8
                    ],
                    "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                    "packagescors": {
                        "score": [
                            60
                        ],
                        "date": [
                            "1615283866457"
                        ]
 {
                    "sequenceno": 1933,
                    "_id": "5eff1",
                    "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
                    "title": "Place Value: 3-digits",
                    "package_description": "This learning module helps to familiarise with the concept of place value of 3-digit numbers.",
                    "age_level": [
                        99,
                        8
                    ],
                    "pkg_sequence": "2501",
                    "packagescors": {
                        "score": [
                            50
                        ],
                        "date": [
                            "1600259121340"
                        ]
                    }
                    }
```

Similar to this there are multiple chapters. So how can I group them so that chapter name comes first then all the related values of chapter comes under that group? What is the proper way to get the values as this

** Update : - I'm trying to use for loop to iterate through the data. What i'm trying to do is to if the key exists group the data accordingly else to add the keys

```
Map<Item,dynamic> sortedTable = {};

Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>> data =  subjectModules.map((e) => e.toMap());
    for (var map in data) {
      try{
        if(sortedTable.containsKey(map['chapter'])){ // if key exists
             // need to add and data group it
            
        }else{ // if not
          sortedTable.putIfAbsent(map['chapter'], () => map); // i need add only keys
        }
      }catch(e){
          print('Error $e');
      }
    }
```

How can i properly iterate and group it??

Answer (score 0):

I have created list of groups by chapter name using `List.forEach` method and `Map.putIfAbsent`.

```
  final resp = {
    "data": {
      "items": [
        {
          "sequenceno": 1933,
          "_id": "5eff1",
          "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
          "title": "Place Value: 3-digits",
          "package_description":
              "This learning module helps to familiarise with the concept of place value of 3-digit numbers.",
          "age_level": [99, 8],
          "pkg_sequence": "2501",
          "packagescors": {
            "score": [50],
            "date": ["1600259121340"]
          }
        },
        {
          "sequenceno": 1933,
          "_id": "5d79",
          "chapter": "Numbers and Numeration",
          "title": "Place Value: 4-digits",
          "package_description":
              "This learning module helps the kids familiarise with the concept of Place value of a number.",
          "age_level": [99, 8],
          "pkg_sequence": "2501",
          "packagescors": {
            "score": [60],
            "date": ["1615283866457"]
          }
        },
        {
          "sequenceno": 1933,
          "_id": "5d79",
          "chapter": "Numbers Numeration",
          "title": "Place Value: 4-digits",
          "package_description":
              "This learning module helps the kids familiarise with the concept of Place value of a number.",
          "age_level": [99, 8],
          "pkg_sequence": "2501",
          "packagescors": {
            "score": [60],
            "date": ["1615283866457"]
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  };

  final ans = {};

  resp["data"]?["items"]?.forEach((e) {
    final entry = ans.putIfAbsent(e["chapter"], () => []);
    entry.add(e);
  });

  print(ans);
```

alternatively you can also use `groupBy` method from [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package.

Comment: Hey @ryg-git , i've been trying it with for loop. I'm trying it to group the data before passing storing to a map.  is there any way that we can only pass the keys first to the map ? I'm also updating my question

Comment: From what I understood from your update on the question I think you want to store the group in the map instead of a list like I did in my answer, if that is the case I think you should select a unique key to store the data as value in the map like `_id` and maybe use this in `else` clause `sortedTable.putIfAbsent(map['chapter'], () => {map['_id']: map});` and in `if` clause `sortedTable[map['chapter']][map['_id']] = map` could be used but I think using List for groups is also a good idea.